# Upgrading a package without breaking ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghc-pkg

In the global package database I have the version 1.3.6.0 of the directory package and I would like to use the version 1.3.6.1 for some project. But in the ghc-8.10.1.conf file there is: depends: (...) directory-1.3.6.0. How can I upgrade the directory package without breaking the ghc-8.10.1 package?

Comment: If the project uses some package manager like Cabal or Stack, perhaps you could add the `1.3.6.1` version of `directory` as an explicit dependency.

Comment: @danidiaz: This solution allows me to build the project indeed but not to install it in a package database that relies on the global  package database. I should mention that I want to install my project and not only to build it.

Comment: If your package is a library, then I recommend not installing it in the global package database anyway -- just do the same thing and use cabal to pull it into other projects that need it. If your package is an executable, then its dependencies do not need to be in the package database for the executable to work.

Comment: @DanielWagner: It is a library. I do not understand how Cabal will find it.

Comment: @user251130 You will tell it where to look. There are various ways, depending on where it's stored (e.g. Hackage vs. github vs. only locally). Hackage is the easiest and most common.